# Importing imblearn in Jupyter is not working

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, imblearn

I have installed imblearn using pip in command in command line and I'm able to import imblearn in python console. but when i use import imblearn in  jupyter i'm getting error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imblearn'".

I know there are many answers in stackoverflow but nothing has worked. Thats the reason i'm posting new question.

[image: Importing imblearn in python console works fine]

[image: While importing imblearn in jupyter i'm getting error]

I tired differnt option like.

1. installing !pip install imblearn in jupyter itself and restarted the kernel.
2. and updating sklearn in jupter.

Please let me know if any other way is there to solve this issue or any other details is required.

Comment: How do you run Jupyter? From the command line or some sort of UI? Are you using a virtual environment? Mind that it is by far recommended to use one.

Comment: I'm running Jupyter from UI only. After installing imblearn in Anaconda powershell prompt, i'm able to import imblearn in Jupyter. Thanks for your time.